Expo router v2 problems
Trying to upgrade to the dreaded Expo v2 (before I continue on to v3 as recommended).  My original code began with the drawer tab consisting of the hamburger drawer and the landing page.  It was all wrapped in my providers and everything worked.
Now with this new routing system and can't get anything to work.  How should I configure so that my app/_layout.js is wrapped in its necessary providers or that it's a child in app/index?
Heres my code.
app
  ->index.js
  ->drawer.js
    ->_layout.js
      ->(home)
      ->index.js
      ->invite.js
  ->[unmatched...].js

app/index.js
return !isLoadingComplete || !fontsLoaded ? null : (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RootSiblingParent>
      <PortalProvider>
        <Slot /> // -> What do I put here?
      </PortalProvider>
    </RootSiblingParent>
  </Provider>
);

app/_layout.js
  return (
    <>
      <Drawer
        drawerPosition="right"
        drawerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: Color.bgPurple,
          width: '55%',
          maxWidth: unity * 200,
          marginRight: 0,
        }}
        drawerContent={(props) => (
          <CustomDrawerContent
            {...{
              ...props,
              authorized,
              userType,
              logout,
              setLoadingStatus,
              setShowModal,
              setModalContent,
              setModalHeight,
            }}
          />
        )}
        initialRouteName="(home)"
        animation="fade"
      >
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="(home)"
          options={{ title: 'Home', headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="invite"
          options={{ title: 'Invite Members', headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Drawer>
      {loading && <Loading message={loadingMessage} />}
      <Toast
        toastMessage={toastMessage}
        onAnimationOutComplete={onToastAnimationOutComplete}
      />
    </>
  );

